# SQL Server - faster records retrieval

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this scenario: one of our tables in a SQL Server database has 50 million rows already. We insert rows in batches from time to time. Every batch has the same batch id and datetimestamp for the row and batch can have up to 100k rows at a time.

There are many batches run during a day. What will be the optimal way of querying to get the first batch rows using the `batchID` and `datetimestamp`?

We have been using min of the batch id and using the corresponding datetimestamp for a while now, but it seems to be not running efficiently. Can you please give some insights to what can be done make this better? Thanks for responses.

Comment: Please provide table structures including indexes and possibly a few rows of example data. I don't see why you are storing the datetimestamp in that table at all if it is the same for all rows in a batch as indicated. And I also don't understand what "first batch records" would mean in that case.

Comment: CREATE TABLE [Test](
[batch_id][int]NOT NULL,
[Claim_ID][varchar](20) NOT NULL,
[Transaction_ID][varchar](255) NULL,
[Transaction_Type] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
[paymentAmount] money,
[EDate] [datetime] NULL)
CONSTRAINT [pk_Test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
[batch_id] ASC,
[Claim_ID] ASC,    
[Transaction_ID] ASC,   
[Transaction_Type] ASC )  THis is the table structure , the first batch records mean the first set of 100k records that got into the table for a day.

Comment: if in each batch the records have the same batchid and datetimestamp, and it has 100K record per batch, should create a table for batchid and stamp, then FK to record table.

Comment: @urlreader i agree , but right now i cannot make this change.Just looking for an optimal way to acheive what i want.

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should add an index for the `EDate`-Column, including the `BatchID`.

```
create nonclustered index Index_EDate_Table 
 on YourTable 
   (EDate ASC)
 include 
   (BatchID)
```

You can then query the Batches of the day ordered by their timestamp as

```
select distinct BatchID
    from YourTable
   where EDate >= Cast(GetDate() as Date)
   order by EDate
```

This should be fast enough.